# Why is ::cmdline::getoptions throwing an error?

Tags: tcl, getopt

Why does the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require cmdline;
set options {{d.arg "" "destination directory"}}
set usage ": $::argv0 \[options] filename ...\noptions:"
set params [::cmdline::getoptions ::argv $options $usage]
```

throw the following error upon execution of `./main.tcl -help`?

```
main : ./main.tcl [options] filename ...
options:
 -d value             destination directory <>
 -help                Print this message
 -?                   Print this message

    while executing
"error [usage $optlist $usage]"
    (procedure "::cmdline::getoptions" line 15)
    invoked from within
"::cmdline::getoptions ::argv $options $usage"
    invoked from within
"set params [::cmdline::getoptions ::argv $options $usage]"
    (file "./main.tcl" line 8)
```

It should display the usage information, but I didn't expect the error afterwards. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from the [docs](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/cmdline/cmdline.html#3) (emphasis mine):

> The options **-?**, **-help**, and **--** are implicitly understood. ***The first two abort option processing by throwing an error and force the generation of the usage message***, whereas the the last aborts option processing without an error, leaving all arguments coming after for regular processing, even if starting with a dash.

using **-help** or **-?** will *always* throw an error.

Further down in the docs you can see an example where `try { ... } trap { ... }` is being used in conjunction with `::cmdline::getoptions`, which might be how you might want to do it:

```
try {
    array set params [::cmdline::getoptions ::argv $options $usage]
} trap {CMDLINE USAGE} {msg o} {
    # Trap the usage signal, print the message, and exit the application.
    # Note: Other errors are not caught and passed through to higher levels!
    puts $msg
    exit 1
}
```